# writeLines not recognising my ratio R

Tags: r

I am trying to use writeLines on a ratio of two columns in my dataset-

```
Name  Height Length
RLM1   200     80
FLM2   300     200
LOP1   170     30
KIM1   320     230
```

So for my code, I have tried the following-

```
writeLines(as.character(df[df$Height/df$Length >2, "Name"]), con='Names.txt')
```

The desired output is if the ratio of height:length is greater than 2, the Name column prints its value. So here, I want RLM1 and LOP1.

The issue I am having is that it is saying error, invalid 'text' argument, which I assume is due to the / in the code but I am not sure.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Name = c("RLM1", "FLM2", "LOP1", "KIM1"),
             Height = c(200, 300, 170, 320),
             Length = c(80, 200, 30, 230))

df %>%
  filter(Height / Length > 2) %>%
  select(Name) %>%
  write_tsv("Names.txt")
```